# How to open a MatDialog with data transmitted by the click on an movie image

Tags: angular, angular-material, components

I'm trying to build a SPA of movies in Angular 9, that consumes data using TMDb api services.

I've already created and consume the data, but when I'm trying to transmit the data to another component called `MoviePopupComponent`, but I have no idea how to do this...

[image: getting data]

I thought and tried to watch some videos about parent and child inheritance and using `@Input`, but I've failed trying to implement it.

```js
export class MovieItemComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public apiService: ApiService, public dialog: MatDialog,){}
  @Input() movie: Movie;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  openModal(movie){
    this.movieObject = this.apiService.getMovieClicked(movie); // Receive the object
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = '80%';
    dialogConfig.height = '90vh';
    this.dialog.open(MoviePopupComponent, dialogConfig);
    this.movieObject.title}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by triggering a function when the movie image was clicked. Opening my modal using ANGULAR MATERIAL Modal. Then I've created a method to get the data from the api using:

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MoviePopUpComponent, data: { /*insert data here*/ } })
```

After that inside my MoviePopupComponent I implemented a injection method by MAT_DIALOG_DATA from Angular Material and it allows me to manipulate the HTML template using the received data:

```
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MoviePopupComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any

<div class="popup">
<div class="header">
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>
        {{ data.original_title }}
    </h2>
    <button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="close()">Close</button>
</div>
<mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img 
            src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1920_and_h800_multi_faces/{{ data.backdrop_path}}" 
            alt="backdrop-img" 
            class="backdrop-img"
        >
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p> {{ data.release_date }} </p>
        <p> {{ data.overview }} </p>
    </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="recommendations">

    </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Data the dialog is suppose to use is part of the config to pass to it. Dont know how I missed it before. Data should be structured in such a way that the `MoviePopupComponent can use.

```
openModal(movie) {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = '80%';
    dialogConfig.height = '90vh';
    dialogConfig.data = {...movieObject};

    this.dialog.open(MoviePopupComponent, dialogConfig)
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to solve this by injecting the data at the moment the user clicks the image and it opens the modal dialog.

Comment: Ah, maybe my updated portion is what you are looking for.

Comment: It's because I'm using angular material, and there's a option to inject the data directly inside the dialog popup. I've tried to use the third argument as this.movie, but the open method doesn't accept more than 2 arguments